# What is Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common doing, and why doesn't it respect my AssemblyResolver?

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

### Background

Currently a Windows application of ours ships with reports using v11 of Microsoft.ReportViewer. We require people to install the matching redistributable, which always struck me as odd, but now I've taken it on myself to upgrade our Microsoft.ReportViewer distribution to v15, which as far as I can tell has no matching redistributable - the 2015 redistributable installs v12 to the global assembly cache (GAC).

This application is not our only application, and we try to standardize support libraries across applications through the use of a Common Files directory. As a result, we also have a static AssemblyResolver class that extends `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` to point to the Common Files directory, or to our debug directory when we're doing development.

### Problem

Our application uses the standard embedded Winforms control to launch ReportViewer. When I try viewing a report in the new version of ReportViewer, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common: at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.AsyncAllStreamsRenderingOperation.RenderLocalReport(LocalReport report)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.AsyncRenderingOperation.PerformOperation()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.AsyncReportOperationWrapper.PerformOperation()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingThread.ProcessThreadMain(Object arg)
   
   Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

There's a much taller inner exception as well:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common: at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ReportRuntime.ProcessLoadingExprHostException(ObjectType assemblyHolderObjectType, Exception e, ProcessingErrorCode errorCode)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ReportRuntime.LoadCompiledCode(IExpressionHostAssemblyHolder expressionHostAssemblyHolder, Boolean includeParameters, Boolean parametersOnly, ObjectModelImpl reportObjectModel, ReportRuntimeSetup runtimeSetup)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Merge.Init(Boolean includeParameters, Boolean parametersOnly)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Merge.Init(ParameterInfoCollection parameters)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.ProcessReportOdp.CreateReportInstance(OnDemandProcessingContext odpContext, OnDemandMetadata odpMetadata, ReportSnapshot reportSnapshot, Merge& odpMerge)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.ProcessReportOdp.Execute(OnDemandProcessingContext& odpContext)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.RenderReportOdpInitial.ProcessReport(ProcessingErrorContext errorContext, ExecutionLogContext executionLogContext, UserProfileState& userProfileState)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.RenderReport.Execute(IRenderingExtension newRenderer)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.RenderReport(IRenderingExtension newRenderer, DateTime executionTimeStamp, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, IChunkFactory yukonCompiledDefinition)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CreateSnapshotAndRender(ReportProcessing repProc, IRenderingExtension renderer, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, SubreportCallbackHandler subreportHandler, ParameterInfoCollection parameters, DatasourceCredentialsCollection credentials)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, String paginationMode, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, IEnumerable dataSources, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)

   Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Yes, that's `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` reporting it can't find `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common`. I was confused too, so I fired up `FUSLOGVW` and logged all the binds, and this is what it tells me happened:

1. Our application tries to find `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms` v15. It checks the GAC, then it checks the immediate application directory, then it checks our extended directory and finds it.
2. `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms` tries to find `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` v15. It checks the GAC, then it checks the immediate application directory, then it checks our extended directory and finds it.
3. `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` tries to find `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel` v15. It checks the GAC, then it checks the immediate application directory, then it checks our extended directory and finds it.
4. **An unknown assembly -- literally, the `FUSLGOVW` log shows Assembly: (unknown)** -- tries to find `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` v15. It checks the GAC, then it checks the immediate application directory, then it gives up and reports it couldn't find anything.

From the timestamps, step 4 there is what's producing the error.

**What's happening here? Why is it happening? Can I tell it to check our extended directory the way other report viewer components have just successfully done?**

I am fine with revising our install procedure to drop the new version of the common DLL in the relevant application directory, but even then I'd need to make the case to our change team and I'd like to be able to say something more than just "Microsoft is weiiiiiiird, you guyyyyyys."

Comment: "There's a much taller inner exception too, but I don't know if it matters." - It might help to determine what _unknown_ assembly is the source of the problem.

Comment: @TnTinMn Is there a way to put it in that doesn't completely clobber the rest of the question? Like, can I do a "click to show more" block?

Comment: The best I know is to wrap it in a `<pre>...</pre>` tag pair. Not the best as it can still take a lot of page space, but eventually it turns into a scroll block.

Comment: @TnTinMn Not nearly as tall as I thought with the hscroll on, fortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common: at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ReportRuntime.ProcessLoadingExprHostException(ObjectType assemblyHolderObjectType, Exception e, ProcessingErrorCode errorCode)
>   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ReportRuntime.LoadCompiledCode(IExpressionHostAssemblyHolder expressionHostAssemblyHolder, Boolean includeParameters, Boolean parametersOnly, ObjectModelImpl reportObjectModel, ReportRuntimeSetup runtimeSetup)
> ```

The following is a decompiled version of the throwing method:

```
internal void LoadCompiledCode(IExpressionHostAssemblyHolder expressionHostAssemblyHolder, bool includeParameters, bool parametersOnly, ObjectModelImpl reportObjectModel, ReportRuntimeSetup runtimeSetup)
{
    if ((expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CompiledCode != null) && (expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CompiledCode.Length > 0))
    {
        try
        {
            if (runtimeSetup.RequireExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions && !expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CompiledCodeGeneratedWithRefusedPermissions)
            {
                if (Global.Tracer.TraceError)
                {
                    Global.Tracer.Trace("Expression host generated with refused permissions is required.");
                }
                throw new ReportProcessingException(ErrorCode.rsInvalidOperation);
            }
            if ((runtimeSetup.ExprHostAppDomain != null) && !ReferenceEquals(runtimeSetup.ExprHostAppDomain, AppDomain.CurrentDomain))
            {
                this.m_exprHostInSandboxAppDomain = true;
                this.m_reportExprHost = ExpressionHostLoader.LoadExprHost(expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CompiledCode, expressionHostAssemblyHolder.ExprHostAssemblyName, includeParameters, parametersOnly, reportObjectModel, expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CodeModules, runtimeSetup.ExprHostAppDomain);
            }
            else
            {
                this.m_exprHostInSandboxAppDomain = false;
                if (expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CodeModules != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CodeModules.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (!runtimeSetup.CheckCodeModuleIsTrustedInCurrentAppDomain(expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CodeModules[i]))
                        {
                            string[] arguments = new string[] { expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CodeModules[i] };
                            this.m_errorContext.Register(ProcessingErrorCode.rsUntrustedCodeModule, Severity.Error, expressionHostAssemblyHolder.ObjectType, null, null, arguments);
                            throw new ReportProcessingException(this.m_errorContext.Messages);
                        }
                    }
                }
                this.m_reportExprHost = ExpressionHostLoader.LoadExprHostIntoCurrentAppDomain(expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CompiledCode, expressionHostAssemblyHolder.ExprHostAssemblyName, runtimeSetup.ExprHostEvidence, includeParameters, parametersOnly, reportObjectModel, expressionHostAssemblyHolder.CodeModules);
            }
        }
        catch (ReportProcessingException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            this.ProcessLoadingExprHostException(expressionHostAssemblyHolder.ObjectType, exception, ProcessingErrorCode.rsErrorLoadingExprHostAssembly);
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the configuration, the code can load a compiled report expression to run in a secondary AppDomain.

Both the [LocalReport.ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms252200(v=vs.90)) and the [LocalReport.ExecuteReportInSandboxAppDomain Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms252173(v=vs.90)) claim in their respective Remarks section to be the *default* mode.  Obviously one of these documentation pages is in error.  I suspect that the true default is ExecuteReportInSandboxAppDomain as this would allow for unloading the compiled expression assembly to release resources.

This poses a problem for your [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve) handler as it is only handling the primary AppDomain resolving problems.

You could try calling the `LocalReport.ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain` method to force using the primary AppDomain.

Comment: I see! If it's standing up its own sandbox to run in that might explain why FUSLOGVW doesn't know what to call it. I'll see if there's something I can do about the run method. Fortunately our report controls are standardized.

Comment: Hm. No, both of those run methods seem to be deprecated in the latest version of the library (you're linking me to a page from VS2008, dunno what version of ReportViewer that is but it's sure not v15). Maybe there's something I can do with the sandbox appdomain permission set...